# ABI Register Names for RISC-V Calling Convention

Tags: cpu-registers, calling-convention, abi, riscv

I'm confused about the RISC-V ABI Register Names. For example, Table 18.2 in the "RISC-V Instruction Set Manual, Volume I: User-Level ISA, Version 2.0" at page 85 specifies that the stack pointer `sp` is register `x14`. However, the instruction

```
addi sp,zero,0
```

is compiled to 0x00000113 by riscv64-unknown-elf-as (`-m32` does not make a difference). In binary:

```
000000000000 00000 000 00010 0010011
^imm         ^rs1  ^f3 ^rd   ^opcode
```

So here `sp` seems to be `x2`. Then I googled a bit and found the [RISC-V Linux User's Manual](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~qmn/linux/riscv.html). This document states that `sp` is `x30`.

So what is it? Are there different ABIs? Can I set the ABI with a command line option to `riscv64-unknown-elf-*`? Is there a comprehensive table somewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The stack pointer is now `x2`.

[Here](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-elf-psabi-doc/blob/master/riscv-cc.adoc#register-convention) is the current ABI documentation, which has been moved out of the [User-Level ISA specification](https://riscv.org/specifications/), which now contains that same link.

The ABI was modified to better accommodate the new RISC-V compressed spec, which puts the 8 most-used registers next to each other in x8-x15.

**Note:** do not trust ANY non riscv.org webpage.  Quan Nguyen makes this clear in his introduction that the "RISC-V Linux User's Manual" is for documenting the porting process and that accuracy is NOT guaranteed.

Comment: Fixed broken link.